# List selection listener does not display until panel is selected

Tags: java, user-interface, jsplitpane

The following code displays a list on the left hand side and the content on the right hand side. So when an item in the list is selected it should display something on the right hand side (this uses split panes). The problems is that it does not display when an item is selected instead it displays it when you click the divider. I was wondering what is wrong with the following code that it does not automatically show the content when and item from the list is selected. Thanks in advance.

Below shows the partial code on where I am having troubles with:

```
public class FrequentQuestions implements ActionListener{

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    frame = new MyInternalFrame("Frequently Asked Questions");

    String [] options = {"How to open/save images", "formats", "info"};
    JList list = new JList(options);
    panelQuestions.add(list);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getValueIsAdjusting())
                return;

            //String [] options2 = {"hello","bye"};
            //JList list2 = new JList(options2);
            JList list = (JList) e.getSource();


            if (list.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("list selection is empty!");
            }
            else{
                int index = ((JList)e.getSource()).getSelectedIndex();
                if(index == 0){
                    readFile();
                }
                else if(index == 1){
                    System.out.println("2nd item selected");

                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("3rd item selected");
                }
            }
        }

    });

    scroll = new JScrollPane(panelAnswers,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, panelQuestions, scroll);
    pane.setAutoscrolls(true);
    pane.setOpaque(true);

    panelQuestions.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,50));
    panelQuestions.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    panelAnswers.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    pane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    pane.setDividerLocation(250);

    frame.add(pane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    desk.add(frame);

     try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e1) {

    }

}
 }
```

Here is the full code (it might not compile because I have the text files, I don't know if this will help):

```
 public class FrequentQuestions implements ActionListener{

private int openFrameCount;
private JDesktopPane desk;
private JTextArea Tarea;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private BufferedReader in ;
JPanel panelQuestions = new JPanel();
JPanel panelAnswers = new JPanel();
JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
//private FrequentQuestions quest;
JSplitPane pane ;
MyInternalFrame frame;

public FrequentQuestions(JDesktopPane desktop) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    desk = desktop;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    frame = new MyInternalFrame("Frequently Asked Questions");

    String [] options = {"How to open/save images", "formats", "Information"};
    JList list = new JList(options);
    //panelQuestions.add(list);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false)
                return;

            String [] options2 = {"hello","bye"};
            JList list2 = new JList(options2);
            JList list = (JList) e.getSource();


            if (list.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("list selection is empty!");
            }
            else{
                int index = ((JList)e.getSource()).getSelectedIndex();
                if(index == 0){
                    readFile();
                    System.out.println("I am outputting!");
                }
                else if(index == 1){
                    readFormatFile();
                    System.out.println("2nd item selected");

                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("3rd item selected");
                }
            }
        }

    });

    JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(list,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(panelAnswers,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scroll1, scroll);
    pane.setAutoscrolls(true);
    pane.setOpaque(true);

    panelQuestions.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(259,50));
    panelQuestions.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    panelAnswers.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(340,30));
    pane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    pane.setDividerLocation(290);


    frame.add(pane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    desk.add(frame);

     try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e1) {

    }

}

private class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;
    public MyInternalFrame(String title) {
        super(title, true,true, true, true);
        setSize(600,500);

        // Set the window's location.
        setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition * openFrameCount);
    }
}

public void readFile(){
    panelAnswers.removeAll();
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("openSave.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String line;
    String file = ""; 
    try {
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            file += line;
            file +="\n";

        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    JTextArea Tarea = new JTextArea();
    //System.out.println(file);

    Tarea.setText(file);
    Font f = new Font("TimesNewRoman", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 12);
    Tarea.setFont(f);
    Tarea.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    Tarea.setEditable(false);
    panelAnswers.add(Tarea);

}

  public void readFormatFile(){
    panelAnswers.removeAll();
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("format.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String line;
    String file = ""; 
    try {
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            file += line;
            file +="\n";

        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    JTextArea Tarea = new JTextArea();
    //System.out.println(file);

    Tarea.setText(file);
    Font f = new Font("TimesNewRoman", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 12);
    Tarea.setFont(f);
    Tarea.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    Tarea.setEditable(false);
    panelAnswers.add(Tarea);

}
 }
```

Comment: What action is you your ActionListener (FrequentQuestions) attached to?

Comment: The FrequentQuestions class is called from the GUI class which contains a button when clicked, it should open a split pane window (which is implemented in this class). I hope that answers your question, I'm kind of unsure about what your asking.

Comment: Your code does not compile, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have put the complete code that I am using. This should hopefully work cause it compiles on mine.

Comment: The main problem is when something on the left hand side is clicked it does not display the info on the right hand side, instead you have to click the divider to display it. I hope that kind of makes sense of what I am having trouble with other than the code works perfectly.

Comment: How can it run for us without a `main` method? What do we need to call in order to see the problem? Post a *minimal* example, not your whole code. Also, use @username to reply to someone in the comments.

Comment: And don't use raw types `JList`, use `JList<type>`.

Comment: @user1803551 its pretty difficult to call it because you need images like x-rays. So I unfortunately don't think you will be able to call it. The rest of my code is pretty complicated and you need external resources to run it. I am just wondering if I could be missing anything.

Comment: You are missing the point. Making a minimal example will show you where your problem is. Your problem is a simple `ListSelectionListener` not working, you don't need the rest of your code. I posted an example which works.

Comment: @user1803551 Thanks, I simplified my own code and this is how you call it.  JMenuItem questions = new JMenuItem("Frequently Asked Questions");
        questions.addActionListener(new FrequentQuestions(desktop));

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: @user1803551 I don't know when I do mine with split panes, then it doesn't work but if its like yours then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working `ListSelectionListener`:

```
public class FrequentQuestions extends JFrame {

    final JLabel label = new JLabel("TEXT");

    public FrequentQuestions() {

        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(new String[]{"A", "B"});
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting())
                    return;
                JList<String> list = (JList<String>) e.getSource();
                label.setText(list.getSelectedValue());
            }
        });

        JSplitPane split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, list, label);
        add(split);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new FrequentQuestions();
    }
}
```

Comment: @selena You want a split pane between the list and the label?

Comment: @selena I added a split pane.

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally worked instead of using the label, I used the text pane and it formatted it very nicely! Thank you again.